# How to use inline file format to query data from stage in Snowflake data warehouse

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there any way to query data from a stage with an inline file format *without copying the data into a table*?

When using a [COPY INTO table](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html) statement, I can specify an inline file format:

```
COPY INTO <table>
FROM (
  SELECT ...
  FROM @my_stage/some_file.csv
)
FILE_FORMAT = (
  TYPE = CSV,
  ...
);
```

However, the same thing doesn't work when running the same select query directly, outside of the `COPY INTO` command:

```
SELECT ...
FROM @my_stage/some_file.csv
(FILE_FORMAT => (
  TYPE = CSV,
  ...
));
```

Instead, the best I can do is to use a pre-existing file format:

```
SELECT ...
FROM @my_stage/some_file.csv
(FILE_FORMAT => 'my_file_format');
```

But this doesn't allow me to programatically change the file format when creating the query. I've tried every syntax variation possible, but this just doesn't seem to be supported right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible but, as a workaround, can't you create the file format programatically, use that named file format in your SQL and then, if necessary, drop it?

Comment: This.  Or create a bunch of set file formats and then programatically choose the one that fits the situation.

Comment: Yeah, might have to do that. I was hoping there'd be a better solution. :(

Answer (score 0):

Check the link below. This worked for me.

```
select t.$1 as PRODUCT_ID, t.$2 as REVIEWDATE 
      from @raw_data/training_data.csv (file_format => 'ff_pipe') t
      where t.$1 is not null
      ;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-stage

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**